# An alternative to os.path.expanduser("~")?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, unicode

In python 2.7.x, `os.path.expanduser("~")` is broken for Unicode.

This means that you get an exception if the expansion of "~" has non-ascii characters in it.

http://bugs.python.org/issue13207

How can I achieve the same, some other way?

(That is to say, how can I get the path to the user's "home directory", which would usually be `C:\Users\usern-name` on Win7)?

Comment: `os.path.expanduser("~")` works for me on Win7 64 bit with Python 2.7 64 bit...

Comment: Right, the problem lies in the way Python 2 handles environment variables on Windows, where Windows hands Python question marks when the codepoints are not encodable. Did you try the [included sample code](http://bugs.python.org/file23442/expanduser.py) that works around the issue by using the Win32 API directly?

Comment: @SaulloCastro: does your path contain codepoints *outside the system codepage*?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't know... how to check that?

Comment: @SaulloCastro: if your call works then *it doesn't*.

Comment: Change your name to "Mark Ørnebjerg" ;)

Comment: @GreenAsJade: which would work if you have the right codepage.. :-P

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't even know what a "codepage" is, so I can't understand the joke!   However, thanks for the pointer to the same workaround code.  I will try it (it takes 24 hour turn around for me to build at Mark Ørnebjerg to test it!)

Comment: @GreenAsJade: Windows terminology for codec, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page. If you configure Windows to use [CP 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_1252) then you can use *Mark Ømebjerg* as a name and Python's `os.path.expanduser()` will work just fine.

Comment: Did you note that the issue you linked also contains a [working solution](http://bugs.python.org/file23442/expanduser.py)? You could simply copy-paste that code, add a bit of code to handle other Oses (which is going to be trivial) and you are done.

Comment: I didn't notice it, but Martjin Pieters pointed it out, a little further up, thanks!

Comment: Note that this is almost always the wrong thing to do in the first place.  There are very few legitimate reasons to be using the user's profile directory.

Comment: @HarryJohnston:  Can you suggest a better way to check if they have a dropbox folder installed in the default place where dropbox folders are installed? By default, dropbox installs it's folder called Dropbox in "~".

Comment: @GreenAsJade: well, I did say *almost* always.  This would indeed be one of the exceptions.  (Though only because you're interacting with someone else's application, and *they* did it wrong...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug report you link to includes a [workaround script](http://bugs.python.org/file23442/expanduser.py), which retrieves the relevant home directory information directly from the Win32 API:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import windll, wintypes

class GUID(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
         ('Data1', wintypes.DWORD),
         ('Data2', wintypes.WORD),
         ('Data3', wintypes.WORD),
         ('Data4', wintypes.BYTE * 8)
    ]

    def __init__(self, l, w1, w2, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8):
        """Create a new GUID."""
        self.Data1 = l
        self.Data2 = w1
        self.Data3 = w2
        self.Data4[:] = (b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8)

    def __repr__(self):
        b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8 = self.Data4
        return 'GUID(%x-%x-%x-%x%x%x%x%x%x%x%x)' % (
                   self.Data1, self.Data2, self.Data3, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8)

# constants to be used according to the version on shell32
CSIDL_PROFILE = 40
FOLDERID_Profile = GUID(0x5E6C858F, 0x0E22, 0x4760, 0x9A, 0xFE, 0xEA, 0x33, 0x17, 0xB6, 0x71, 0x73)

def expand_user():
    # get the function that we can find from Vista up, not the one in XP
    get_folder_path = getattr(windll.shell32, 'SHGetKnownFolderPath', None)
    if get_folder_path is not None:
        # ok, we can use the new function which is recomended by the msdn
        ptr = ctypes.c_wchar_p()
        get_folder_path(ctypes.byref(FOLDERID_Profile), 0, 0, ctypes.byref(ptr))
        return ptr.value
    else:
        # use the deprecated one found in XP and on for compatibility reasons
       get_folder_path = getattr(windll.shell32, 'SHGetSpecialFolderPathW', None)
       buf = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(300)
       get_folder_path(None, buf, CSIDL_PROFILE, False)
       return buf.value
```

This `expand_user()` function returns the home directory for the current user only.

Comment: Thanks - I'll accept the answer after it's tested (it works locally, but I don't have a troublesome username!).  You even edited out the pdb!! :)

Comment: Well - it works :)   One thing I'm a little worried about - further comments in the bug report mentioned that "using ctypes is risky", or somesuch, and the ticket was closed as "wontfix".  Why didn't they apply the patch that I am using, which you have quoted above?

Comment: The bug report mostly states they are not going to fix it because it is too much work. `ctypes` requires the DLLs to be available at runtime, something you cannot *guarantee* in all cases; Python devs prefer relying on functionality you can test for at compile (install) time instead.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments you actually need a WinAPI call to obtain the value of the `USERPROFILE` environment variable:

```
import ctypes

buf = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(1024)
ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetEnvironmentVariableW(u"USERPROFILE", buf, 1024)
home_dir = buf.value
```

or, if you prefer the dedicated shell function:

```
CSIDL_PROFILE = 40
buf = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(1024)
ctypes.windll.shell32.SHGetFolderPathW(None, CSIDL_PROFILE, None, 0, buf)
print buf.value
```

Note that both snippets return the profile path, this is not necessary the same as home path.

Comment: That's *the problem*, the `os.environ` dictionary contains bytestrings encoded using the system codepage, and Windows hands you question marks if codepoints cannot be encoded in that codepage. Which means that those environment variables contain `/?????` characters for anything outside the configured Windows codepage even though the filesystem uses UTF-16 to encode this info.

Comment: Actually, I don't even get question marks, I get an exception:  File "ntpath.py", line 301, in expanduser Unicode decode error ...

Comment: I wonder if this means it would "just work" if I passed a b"~" to expanduser(), or whether all this would change is that I'd get ??? instead of exception, which is just as bad!

Comment: @GreenAsJade: sorry, I was looking at the current revision of `ntpath.py`; you have an older version, my analysis was incorrect. What version of Python 2.7 do you have, exactly?

Comment: 2.7.6, though that eerror message came from 2.7.2 (I upgraded to 2.7.6 after I got that error message reported to me, but upgrading didn't fix it)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: thanks for pointing this out, I added a WinAPI workaround.